# What am I doing wrong with erl_parse:parse_form?

Tags: erlang

I wrote a Hello-World module and compiled it successfully. And then I tried to learn the things under the hood by using erl_scan and erl_parse.

```
-module(useless).                                                    
-export([hello/0]).                                               

hello() -> io:format("hello world\n").
```

and I type in the `erl` shell

```
{ok, S} = file:read_file("useless.erl").
```

and

```
{ok, T, _} = erl_scan:string(binary_to_list(S)).
```

It works fine apparently. But when I try `erl_parse:parse_form(T).`

It gives `{error,{2,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'-'"]}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
the module [*compile*](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html) is helpful.

Also [this](http://studzien.github.io/hack-vm/part1.html#slide-0) is cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function erl_parse:parse_form/1 works on one form only. So you must split the result of erl_scan:string/1 into individual forms first.

you can use erl_scan:tokens to achieve this (this code wors, but I am not sure I use the function in the right way):

```
-module(useless).                                                    
-export([eval/1]).                                               

eval(File) -> 
    {ok, B} = file:read_file(File),
    Forms = scan(erl_scan:tokens([],binary_to_list(B),1),[]),
    F = fun(X) -> {ok,Y} = erl_parse:parse_form(X), Y end,
    [F(X) || X <- Forms].

scan({done,{ok,T,N},S},Res) ->
    scan(erl_scan:tokens([],S,N),[T|Res]);
scan(_,Res) ->
    lists:reverse(Res).
```

Comment: `erl_scan:tokens/3` is re-entrant so it can handle getting in the input characters in chunks and keep collecting until it gets all the characters it needs (up to a '. '). You do not use it in this way but the way you do use it works.

Comment: One improvement you could do is take the line number returned from `erl_scan:tokens` in the `{ok,Ts,Line}` return value and use that in the next call to `erl_scan:tokens`.

Comment: I modified the code according to Robert suggestion. Hopefully it works :o) even better since the line numbers in the result are correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Robert suggestion is to use the re-entrant feature of `erl_scan:tokens/3`. 
The docs on this function are not explicit and it took me some time to understand that the initial string needed to be closed by `eof`. (if not the tokens function runs an endless loop).

Here is the code I finally came up with, I hope that will help others.

```
eval(File)->
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file(File),
    String=erlang:binary_to_list(Data),
    scan(String).

scan(String) when is_list(String)->
    scan(String++eof,[]). %% appended eof

scan({done, Result, LeftOverChars},Acc)->
    scan_done(Result,LeftOverChars,Acc);
scan({more, Continuation},Acc)->
    scan(erl_scan:tokens(Continuation,[],1),Acc);
scan(String,Acc) when is_list(String)->
    scan(erl_scan:tokens([],String,1),Acc).

scan_done({error,ErrorMsg,_Location},_LeftOverChars,_Acc)->
    ErrorMsg;
scan_done({eof,Location},LeftOverChars,Acc)->
    Acc;
scan_done({ok,Tokens,Location},LeftOverChars,Acc)->
    case erl_parse:parse_form(Tokens) of
    {ok,R}->scan(LeftOverChars,Acc++[R]);
    {error,R}->scan(LeftOverChars,R)
    end.
```