# How can I use erl_lint to syntax check an Erlang module?

Tags: syntax, erlang

I'm trying to use erl_lint() to build a simple Erlang syntax and style checker. I've gotten far enough to load the file and parse it into Forms and to get erl_lint to partially understand it, but then erl_lint complains about undefined functions that are defined. What am I doing wrong?

erlint.erl :

```
-module(erlint).
-export([lint/1]).

% based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/28086396/13675

lint(File) -> 
    {ok, B} = file:read_file(File),
    Forms = scan(erl_scan:tokens([],binary_to_list(B),1),[]),
    F = fun(X) -> {ok,Y} = erl_parse:parse_form(X), Y end,
    erl_lint:module([F(X) || X <- Forms],File).

scan({done,{ok,T,N},S},Res) ->
    scan(erl_scan:tokens([],S,N),[T|Res]);
scan(_,Res) ->
    lists:reverse(Res).
```

hello.erl :

```
-module(hello).
-export([hello_world/0]).

hello_world() -> io:fwrite("hello, world\n").
```

attempt to use :

```
1> c(erlint).
{ok,erlint}
2> erlint:lint("hello.erl").
{error,[{"hello.erl",
         [{2,erl_lint,{undefined_function,{hello_world,0}}}]}],
       []}
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the entire compiler up to some point?

Comment: @aronisstav I anticipate getting more useful and fine-tune-able information out of erl_lint than I can get by manipulating the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this approach fits with your overall plan, but you could instead compile the input file, extract its abstract forms from the resulting beam, and pass them to `erl_lint`:

```
-module(erlint).
-export([lint/1]).

lint(File) ->
    {ok,_,Bin} = compile:file(File,[debug_info,binary]),
    {ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(Bin,[abstract_code]),
    erl_lint:module(AC,File).
```

Let's change your `hello.erl` to include an unused variable:

```
-module(hello).
-export([hello_world/0]).

hello_world() ->
    X = io:fwrite("hello, world\n").
```

We see that this version of `erlint:lint/1` correctly reports it:

```
1> erlint:lint("hello.erl").
{ok,[{"hello.erl",[{5,erl_lint,{unused_var,'X'}}]}]}
```

If you need them for your overall purposes, note that you can retrieve source code forms from the abstract forms variable `AC` by calling `erl_syntax:form_list(AC)`.

Comment: I anticipate many situations where compilation would fail with a single error, while linting parsed forms of the whole module would provide additional info prior to fixing the compilation failure.